# Win7 set my FAT32 USB key as read-only; can't format it

Tags: windows-7, usb, format, fat32

Today, I backed up some stuff from a Win7 before migrating to Ubuntu. In the middle of copying the files on my FAT32 USB key, Windows set the key as read-only. Now, I need to format the key to put a LiveUSB on it, but I can't.
Weirdly enough, I can manage the files from another GNU/Linux PC (where /dev/sdb is the key).

## **What I've tried**

- **Diskpart :** Read-only is on No, but current read-only state is on Yes. I can't do anything as it's read-only
- **GParted on a GNU/Linux :** Delete button is grayed, and when resizing, it tells me that there's an unfinished FAT table.
- **Regedit -> StorageDevicePolicies :** Nothing happened.
- **"sudo dosfsck -t -a /dev/sdb" :** No results.
- **"sudo fsck.vfat -r /dev/sdb" :** Prompts me to choose a FAT, both choices asks me to correct a "Free cluster summary wrong", but no results.
- **"sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb"** : No results.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to zero the device (note: this will destroy data on it). This command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

will zero the whole device; this may not be necessary, since zeroing only the first 512 bytes may be enough:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

Invoke one command or the other (start with the 2nd one), wait for it to finish, remove the device from USB port, wait few seconds, reinsert, create partitions from scratch and format.

In case dd cannot write to device, I have a clue:

I know there are USB keys that are in fact microSD cards in USB adapter. What brand is Your USB key? No-name or exotic one? Wikipedia informs:
"The host device can command the SD card to become read-only (to reject subsequent commands to write information to it). There are both reversible and irreversible host commands that achieve this."
Maybe Your key is a SD card (in disguise) that was rendered read-only due to some bug or error (in adapter firmware? the card itself?). Just guessing.

Comment: Error from GParted : "I/O error" while trying to create a partition table. 
In French : disk label not recognized

Comment: Oh well it worked with the first command. Thanks a lot!